# Uncheck all other checkboxes if one is checked

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, checkbox

I've used a XAML ListView and one of the columns in the Listview is a checkbox.when the data is bound to the ListView it creates multiple rows with on of the column as a checkbox. The problem I'm facing I want the user to be able to select only one checkbox whereas right now he can select multiple.All other check boxes should get unchecked when user selects one.

This is the XAML part.

```
<ListView  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Name="ClientList" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="#cccccc" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20,10,60,0" >

                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView  ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1}">
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Client Name " x:Name="clienteName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ClientName}"  Width="390"  />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Client Code " x:Name="ClienteCode" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ClientCode}"  Width="195" />
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Select" Width="57">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <Grid >
                                            <CheckBox DataContext="{Binding ClientCode}"  Click="CheckBox_Click" TouchDown="CheckBox_TouchDown"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>

                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

CS used for binding the data to the ListView

```
List<Client> list = new List<Client>();
ClientList.Items.Clear();
list = getListFromDT(dt);

foreach (Client pr in list)
{
   ClientList.Items.Add(pr);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like what you actually want is a RadioButton...

Comment: @doubleYou I want a CheckBox to behave like a RadioButton or I could use a RadioButton which looks like a CheckBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please use RadioButton - it has the needed behavior. If you want it to look like a checkbox then change the RadioButtons style to look like a checkbox.
2. If you still want to use CheckBox - then foreach ( var item in GridView ) is your option.

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like this ?

```
  void check_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox sendercheck = sender as CheckBox;
        if (sendercheck.Checked)
        {
            foreach (var c in Container.Children)
            {
                CheckBox check = c as CheckBox;
                if (check != null)
                {
                    if (check.Id != sendercheck.Id)
                    {
                        check.Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the container here should be your list